# R retrieving values from data.tables while within custom functions

Tags: r, data.table

I'm trying to retrive a value from a datatable as part of a larger custom function. I can gnerate the row number, but I can't retrive the values from that row. The formula works outside of the function environment but not inside.

```
example_outlier_table <- data.table(dataset = c("doe", "ray", "me", "fa", "so"),
                                    upper_limit = c(2,6,9,11,7))

example_function <- function(dt,otable){
  return(match(deparse(substitute(dt)), otable$dataset))
}

example_function(ray, example_outlier_table)
```

result = 2

This is correct, 'ray' is the second entry in the 'dataset' column

In this example, 'ray' is both the character string in 'example_outlier_table$dataset' and the name of another data table object, hence the  'deparse(substitute(dt))' step.

The issue is this: I want to use the value that 'ray' indicates in the example_outlier_table, number 6, in another place within my custom function.

```
example_function <- function(dt,otable){
  return(otable[dataset == as.character(deparse(substitute(dt))), 
                upper_limit])
}

example_function(ray, example_outlier_table)
```

result = numeric(0)
incorrect

```
example_function <- function(dt,otable){
  return(otable[match(deparse(substitute(dt)), otable$dataset), 
                upper_limit])
}

example_function(ray, example_outlier_table)
```

result = [1] NA

Comment: The issue in your last piece of code is that the `deparse(substitute` should be done at the first instance and i.e. `dt <- deparse(substitute(dt));
  return(otable[match(dt, otable$dataset), 
                upper_limit])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could directly extract the column with `[[`

```
example_function <- function(dt,otable){
   dt <- deparse(substitute(dt))
    otable[["upper_limit"]][otable[["dataset"]] == dt]
}
```

-testing

```
example_function(ray, example_outlier_table)
[1] 6
```

---

Or using the `data.table` methods

```
example_function <- function(dt,otable){
   dt <- deparse(substitute(dt))
    otable[dataset == dt, upper_limit][[1]]
}
example_function(ray, example_outlier_table)
[1] 6
```

Comment: Thankyou, I successfully integrated the first method into my actual function and it worked successfully.

Comment: I changed it slightly to 
```
otable[["upper_limit"]][otable[["dataset"]] == deparse(substitute(dt))]
```
and it worked. Interestingly, both methods work as you wrote them, but changing the second method to
```
`otable[dataset == deparse(substitute(dt)), upper_limit][[1]]`

gives a "subscript out of bounds" error.

Comment: @BenRoberts I wouldn't recommend using `deparse/substitute` at  a later stage.  It should be the done at the top

Comment: @BenRoberts i.e. according to `?substitute` `Substitution takes place by examining each component of the parse tree as follows: If it is not a bound symbol in env, it is unchanged. If it is a promise object, i.e., a formal argument to a function or explicitly created using delayedAssign(), the expression slot of the promise replaces the symbol.`

Comment: Thanks, i will look into the `substitute()` docs further